# Include editable=false fields in ModelFormSet

Tags: python, django, django-forms, readonly

I have a Django model with a `created_on` field set to `editable=False`. This is the correct behavior because I have also set `auto_now=True` and per the documentation:

> "As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True
>   will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set."

Using the admin, you can define any fields you have set to `editable=False` as `readonly_fields` in the `ModelAdmin` and everything will work as expected (i.e. the fields will show up in the form, but they will be grayed out).

However, when working with a ModelFormSet in an app (i.e. not the admin), I cannot figure out how to show the `created_on` field in the forms. Per the documentation:

> "Django applies the following rule: if you set editable=False on the
>   model field, any form created from the model via ModelForm will not
>   include that field."

Does anybody know of a way to override/circumvent that behavior?

I would rather not set `editable=True` because it is a constraint I want to maintain at the most basic level. I probably can't set it to `True` anyways if I'm using `auto_now=True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching for a solution I finally figured it out. It is possible to get and populate data for a field which has editable=false by:

1. Adding the field definition to the ModelForm class
2. Adding an `__init__` method which instantiates the value of the field
3. Adding adding the field to the *fields* tuple in the Class Meta definition of the ModelForm class

For example:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    created_on = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance:
            if not self.initial.get('created_on'):
                self.initial['created_on'] = self.instance.created_on

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'etc', 'created_on')
```